# Calcular longitud textarea

Tags: javascript

Tengo una validación de caracteres restantes, como está ahora solamente detecta teclas presionadas y valida que sea una tecla permitida, pero si seleccionas varios caracteres y los borras solo te lo detecta como una sola tecla presionada, lo que quiero es calcular basado en el numero de caracteres que hay en el textarea.

```js
let limite = 30;
let char = document.getElementById("caracteres");
let texto = document.getElementById("textarea");
let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
char.innerHTML = +limite;
textarea.onkeydown = function (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90 || e.keyCode === 32) {
        char.innerHTML = --limite;
        console.log(limite - document.getElementById("textarea").value.lenght);
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 8 && char.innerText < 30) {
        char.innerHTML = ++limite;
    }
    if (char.innerText < 0) {
        texto.style.color = "red";
    }
    if (char.innerText >= 0) {
        texto.style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="texto">Puedes escribir hasta <span id="caracteres"></span> caracteres restantes</span><br>
<textarea name="texto" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: No se si te vale, pero textarea tiene una propiedad que es maxlength y que te limita el numero de cararcteres a introducir

Comment: tienes **maxlength** y **minlength** como propiedad para poder limitar el textarea, ahora si queires hacerlo bonito como lo estas aciendo tendras que ponerle javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GreenLass. Prueba con lo siguiente, a ver si te vale...

```
const limite = 30,
    char = document.getElementById("caracteres"),
    textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
char.innerHTML = +limite;
textarea.onkeyup = function () {
    let longitud = textarea.value.length;
    
    char.innerHTML = (limite-longitud);
    
    
    if (char.innerText < 0) {
        texto.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        texto.style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente gracias

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema viene por esto:

```
if (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    char.innerHTML = --limite;
    console.log(limite - document.getElementById("textarea").value.lenght);
}
if (e.keyCode === 8 && char.innerText < 30) {
    char.innerHTML = ++limite;
}
```

Usas el evento para sumar o restar, dependiendo de la tecla pulsada, pero no deberia ser asi, sino que deberia coger el valor del `length` de tu textbox.

Algo asi:

```
var a = document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML.length;
console.log(a)
```

Esto se lanzaria por cada evento de tecla, asi si te seleccionan varios y lo borran no pasara nada.

Saludos.

Hay un error de sintaxis en el código siguiente, creo que es de Srsole, indicado mas arriba (yo suelo cometerlo)

... console.log(limite - document.getElementById("textarea").value.lenght)

debe decir: length

En lo demás, es muy buena la respuesta

Comment: El codigo esta copiado de la pregunta, no lo revise a profundidad.